# Operating with booleans in PHP

Tags: php, boolean-operations

Well, I come from compiled languages as Java and now I am trying to deal with PHP in some specific areas. Today, I have created a "test form" in order to know how to check for valid values, and now I have a little problem.

Suppose that I  have multiple fields to evaluate, using a boolean variable I would like to do something like this:

```
//ASSUMING THAT ALL IS CORRECT
$correct =  true;

$correct &= is_ok($name);
$correct &= is_ok($last_name);
$correct &= is_ok($nickname);
$correct &= is_ok($best_friend);

if (!$correct) {
    //AT LEAST ONE FIELD IS INCOMPLETE
}
else
{
    // EVERYTHING IS OK
}

function is_ok($field){
    return !empty($field);
}
```

The problem that I am issuing is that `&=` looks like is not working correctly. Do I need to use another boolean operator?

Comment: This is not valid PHP code. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Read some PHP tutorials first, then try again.

Comment: check out the part on $variables for starters.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I have updated the post. That is my code. Guys, sorry.. all of them were typos

Comment: `&=` - What do you think this is doing?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, the idea is :  `$correct = $correct & is_ok($foo)`. But it does not work.

Comment: I don't believe PHP supports that operator; I believe, but can't find in the manual, that that's actually a reference operator.

Comment: I tried that operator and it works on PHP 5.3.13. `$a &= $b` is the same as `$a = $a & $b`.

Comment: In fact the operator `&=` is valid and works as what the @manix wanted. See: https://gist.github.com/3481335

Comment: @mauris, it is exactly I was looking for, and I thought that this operator was not valid in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always read manual first:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Bitwise operatiors != Logical operators

I think you are looking for this:

```
//ASSUMING THAT ALL IS CORRECT
$correct =  true;

$correct = $correct && is_ok($name);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($last_name);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($nickname);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($best_friend);
```

You should start form tutorials, basic lessons, basic documentation to avoid that kind of questions.

Comment: Hey, useful! but you know what? I tried to reproduced the "string short concatanation" like `$string .= $foo` but applied to booleans and it confused me a little bit

Comment: @manix Thats ok, But 1. still `&` is not logical operator. 2. why do you try to reproduce something instead read manual?

Comment: I will keep it in mind! Thanks you for your help and the rest of people too.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_ok($name) && is_ok($last_name) && is_ok($nickname) && is_ok($best_friend)) {
  echo "Good.";  
} else{
  echo "Bad.";
}
```

Or more simply

```
if (!empty($name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($nickname) && !empty($best_friend)) {
  echo "Good.";  
} else{
  echo "Bad.";
}
```

If you really want to write it the way you wanted to write it:

```
$correct = true;
$correct = $correct && is_ok($name);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($last_name);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($nickname);
$correct = $correct && is_ok($best_friend);
```

Comment: This is sooo unclever. `:P` To wit, I'd probably just make `is_ok()` accept one or more variables to test. Make it simpler.

Comment: The last one is what I was searching for! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

& is bitwise operator. For bloolean use &&, like

```
`$correct =  $correct && is_ok($name);`
```

because

```
echo 1 & 2
```

gives 0